# How to make the user enter either of the 2 fields

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder=" Enter First Name" required/><input type="hidden" name="search" value="true" >

<input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" /><input type="hidden" name="search" value="true" >
```

I have got these 2 text boxes and I am using these text boxes for searching users on a webpage.

I want the users can search using both these text boxes.

I have written the query for that but I am facing a problem, if user writes anything in either of the text boxes then it should not show any error on the front end but if user leaves both text fields empty then an error should be generated and I want to do it on the design page.

I don't want to write a validation code for that.

I have tried `required` field but it does not work in my case as  either of the 2 text boxes should be input with data.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to do it on the design page . I don't want to write a validation code for that". 
You mean you want validation done in UI through javascript and avoid validation in server side?

Comment: Without writing any Javascript validation function if you want to do it.Then you have to include the input type in form tag

Comment: yes i want to avoid validation on server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do validation in UI, please follow the below steps

1) Provide id's to both the input fields, which are used to validate the fields

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder=" Enter First Name" required/><input type="hidden" name="search" value="true" >
       <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" /><input type="hidden" name="search" value="true" >
```

2) Using javascript you can valiate as below

```
function validate() {
    if(document.getElementById("firstname").value.trim() != "" && document.getElementById("lastname").value.trim() != "" ) {
// show alert saying required input fields.
} else {
// do the submit action
}
}
```

3) Call the validate function on submit of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery/java script you can do client side validation..

Your HTML

```
<input type="text"  id="first" name="firstname" placeholder=" Enter First Name" /><input type="hidden" name="search" value="true" >
       <input type="text" id ="last" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" /><input type="hidden" name="search" value="true" >
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="check"/>
```

Validation

```
$("#button1").click(function()
                    {
$first=$("#first").val();
$sec=$("#last").val();
if(($first=="")&&($sec==""))
{
    alert("Please enter any");
}
                    });
```